# "No-referrer-when-downgrade" Nginx 502

Tags: nginx

I have a 502 error on some pages of my site, I do not understand why some pages work but others display this error:

> Request Method:POST
>   Status Code:502 Bad Gateway
>   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: You are going to have to be a bit more forthcoming in providing information. Where's your code? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on how to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem

You have the [Referer Policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) set to "no-referer-when-downgrade" in Nginx, which means referer information (as your form URL) is not sent in case of downgrade (httpS submitting to simple http). And your code behind doesn't like not having this piece of information.

## Solutions

1. Best is to pass everything to http**s** :)
2. Change in your nginx.conf, the policy to:

   ```
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'same-origin';
   ```
3. If 2. doesn't work, please do as said in 1., or you can also (but **please
   don't do that**, it's very unsecure):

   ```
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'unsafe-url';
   ```

---

***More:**
[Mozilla's reference documentation about Referer Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy).*

**Note:**
`origin` will only set the base URL with no URI like `https://domain-name.com/`. While `same-origin` will set the full Secure URL as the Referer if it's from the same domain. It's secure since the header is passed on the `:433` secure port listening.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the place where to put the configuration? Do you have an example?

Comment: @Paolo nginx.conf is located in various places depending on your operating system. On debian it's in /etc/nginx/ Google "nginx.conf your operating system"

Comment: Thank you Erdal, I opened this question with more details, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002830/no-referrer-when-downgrade-error-angular-app-on-firebase-connecting-to-nginx-j the problem is that I tried to put this line in the conf but with no results.

Comment: Thanks, from the W3C doc, `add_header Referrer-Policy 'same-origin';` is the way for me if I want get the Referer's full URL. `origin` stays at domain URL with no URI.

Comment: @KeitelDOG Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue setting up Sonarqube. Sonarqube runs on 127.0.0.1:9000 by default, however, I was trying to access the browser with the private IP address. I made the same mistake of putting that IP address in the configuration below:

```
server { 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<server_ip>:<port>;
    }
}
```

I had made the mistake of setting it to the actual private IP address of the server, when I should have just made it `http://localhost:<port>;`

After doing that my application had worked properly... I hope that helps.