# login into gmail fails for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to login into my gmail with puppeteer to lower the risk of recaptcha

here is my code

```
    await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=mail&amp;continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/', {timeout: 60000})
        .catch(function (error) {
            throw new Error('TimeoutBrows');
        });

    await page.waitForSelector('#identifierId' , { visible: true });
    await page.type('#identifierId' , 'myemail');
    await Promise.all([
        page.click('#identifierNext') ,
        page.waitForSelector('.whsOnd' , { visible: true })
    ])
    await page.type('#password .whsOnd' ,  "mypassword");
    await page.click('#passwordNext');
    await  page.waitFor(5000);
```

but i always end up with this message

[image]

I even tried to just open the login window with puppeteer and fill the login form manually myself, but even that failed.

Am I missing something ?

When I look into console there is a failed ajax call  just after login.

```
Request URL: https://accounts.google.com/_/signin/challenge?hl=en&TL=APDPHBCG5lPol53JDSKUY2mO1RzSwOE3ZgC39xH0VCaq_WHrJXHS6LHyTJklSkxd&_reqid=464883&rt=j
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: 216.58.213.13:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade


)]}'

[[["er",null,null,null,null,401,null,null,null,16]
,["e",2,null,null,81]
]]
```

Comment: Any error messages in the response?

Comment: @AviMeltser i've uploaded the error image ,in case you cant see the image it just says `something wen wrong , try again`

Comment: No, I mean in the console perhaps or in the http response, something that can shed more light on the type of error

Comment: whatever cannot be produced manually barely can be automated. you're probably even referring to an outdated example, because somehow I get different parameters, when trying that.

Comment: 401 error code means Unauthorized. It's highly likely your credentials are wrong

Comment: @AviMeltser either that - or the credentials are not being passed in the expected way.

Comment: @AviMeltser o found a failed ajax call fired right after login ... i've added to question  ... the credentials  are correct otherwise it would have said so ... instead of showing unknown error

Comment: @MartinZeitler i think there is a simple solution , i have to add something to parameters of config or something ..... i mean its just a browser

Comment: @MartinZeitler agreed. @hreric your updated error message might mean [you need to set the `Referrer-Policy` header of your http request to 'origin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319054/no-referrer-when-downgrade-nginx-502). Perhaps puppeteer is trying to downgrade from https to http after receiving the response.

Comment: Afaik, Puppeteer is made by google team, with lots of flags, google surely knows it's an automated browser and obviously will try to prevent you from various actions. I think, you will need to deal with bot prevention mechanisms first.

Comment: @hretic, can I see the the wrap around your code? I've just run and it seems valid (despite some selectors and timeouts). Do you run your code in headless mode or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've inspected your code and it seems to be correct despite of some selectors. Also, I had to add a couple of timeouts in order to make it work. However, I failed to reproduce your issue so I'll just post the code that worked for me.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=mail&amp;continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/', {timeout: 60000})
        .catch(function (error) {
            throw new Error('TimeoutBrows');
        });

    await page.screenshot({path: './1.png'});
    ...

})();
```

**Please, note that I run browser in normal, not headless mode.** If you take a look at screenshot at this position, you will see that it is correct Google login form
[image: Google login form after the first step]

The rest of the code is responsible for entering password

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    ...
    await page.waitForSelector('#identifierId', {visible: true});
    await page.type('#identifierId', 'my@email');
    await Promise.all([
        page.click('#identifierNext'),
        page.waitForSelector('.whsOnd', {visible: true})
    ]);

    await page.waitForSelector('input[name=password]', {visible: true});
    await page.type('input[name=password]', "my.password");

    await page.waitForSelector('#passwordNext', {visible: true});
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    await page.click('#passwordNext');
    await page.waitFor(5000);

})();
```

Please also note few differences from your code - the selector for password field is different. I had to add `await page.waitForSelector('#passwordNext', {visible: true});` and a small timeout after that so the button could be clicked successfully.

I've tested all the code above and it worked successfully. Please, let me know if you still need some help or facing troubles with my example.

Comment: hi ,can you navigate to gmail index and see your emails after login ?  cuz i can login  but after login i get this error

Comment: @hretic, yes I can. Did you try to copy and paste my code and run it?

Comment: @hretic, here you can see a proof: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Erc-8M_p0KR2yOUnr1vkPFocYUq8dxE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @hretic, have you succeed with your challenge? Was my example helpful or do you need any additional help?

Comment: hey sorry about delay , i lost my HDD and were trying to retrieve my data somehow

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of question is to login to Gmail. I will share another method that does not involve filling email and password fields on puppeteer script
and works in `headless: true` mode.

## Method

- Login to your gmail using normal browser (google chrome preferebbly)
- Export all cookies for the gmail tab
- Use `page.setCookie` to import the cookies to your puppeteer instance

### Login to gmail

This should be no brainer.

### Export all cookies

I will use an extension called [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en), however you can use other extensions or manual methods to extract the cookies.

Click the browser icon and then click the **Export** button.

[image]

### Import cookies to puppeteer instance

We will save the cookies in a cookies.json file and then import using [page.setCookie](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.17.0/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies) function **before navigation**. That way when gmail page loads, it will have login information right away.

The code might look like this.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cookies = require('./cookies.json');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // Set cookies here, right after creating the instance
  await page.setCookie(...cookies);
  // do the navigation, 
  await page.goto("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/stackoverflow+survey", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    timeout: 60000
  });
  await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

### Result:

[image]

### Notes:

It was not asked, but I should mention following for future readers.

- **Cookie Expiration**: Cookies might be short lived, and expire shortly after, behave differently on a different device. Logging out on your original device will log you out from the puppeteer as well since it's sharing the cookies.
- **Two Factor**: I am not yet sure about 2FA authentication. It did not ask me about 2FA probably because I logged in from same device.