# Which Referrer Policy is the safest?

Tags: jquery, post, policy, referrer

I am working on a website and it also receives POST requests from my mobile phone app unfortunately I am not familiar with the **Referrer Policy** and these are currently on my website default so browser-dependent so it is in Firefox: `no-referrer-when-downgrade` and at Microsoft Edge: `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`.

> **I would like to understand which would be the best choice for me and**
> **whether I should change anything at all?**

Comment: [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

Comment: Ok so `no-referrer-when-downgrade` is the best in my case?

Comment: The safest would be `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`.

Comment: I saw `same-origin` is even safer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319054/no-referrer-when-downgrade-nginx-502/49326278#answer-49326278